# Listing values within enums using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, windows, reflection, enums

I am trying to use reflection to list the public members and methods of a few classes in various projects inside of one Visual Studio solution.  All of the classes I am trying to access are C# and they are all being accessed from a C# class.  The code I'm using to make these calls is as follows:

```
public void PopulateEventParamTree()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(source.GetType().ToString());
        Type type = (Type)source.getEventType();
        System.Console.WriteLine(type.ToString());

        foreach (MemberInfo member in type.GetMembers())
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("\t" + member.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Most of the outputs work fine (i.e. Int32, Double, System.String).  My problem is that when I try to list enums I get an output to the console that looks like this:

```
Namespace.Subspace.event+EVENT_TYPE
```

I would like to be able to see all of the inner values of the enum instead of just its name.  For example, the enum

```
public enum EVENT_TYPE
{
    EVENTDOWN,
    EVENTMOVE,
    EVENTUP,
}
```

should output something like this

```
Namespace.Subspace.class+EVENT_TYPE EVENTDOWN
Namespace.Subspace.class+EVENT_TYPE EVENTMOVE
Namespace.Subspace.class+EVENT_TYPE EVENTUP
```

Any help that anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.  I've exhausted everything I've been able to find thus far but a fresh perspective would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(EVENT_TYPE))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx).

you will probably have to deal this special case (not using reflection for enums).

Comment: [@Craigt answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005931/listing-values-within-enums-using-reflection-in-c/5006004#5006004) may be more accurate in your context. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 14):

how to get enum and values via reflection

```
var importAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile("test.dll");     
Type[] types = importAssembly.GetTypes();
     foreach (Type type in types)
        {
        if (type.IsEnum)
        {
               var enumName=type.Name;
               foreach (var fieldInfo in type.GetFields())
               {
                  if (fieldInfo.FieldType.IsEnum)
                  {
                      var fName=fieldInfo.Name;
                      var fValue=fieldInfo.GetRawConstantValue();
                  }
              }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

So in your case checking if source is an enum type and then calling GetEnumNames() would allow the code to act on classes, enums etc.

```
    private void Work()
    {
        var type = typeof(numbers);

        string [] members;

        if(type.IsEnum)
            members = typeof(numbers).GetEnumNames();
    }

    public enum numbers
    {
        one,
        two,
        three,
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The enums are implemented as public static readonly fields (probably also const); your current code should work... You just need to get the name from the FieldInfo. And call GetValue if you want the value.

However, Enum.GetValues(type) is easier...

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to call in few lines

```
public enum TestEnum // in some assembly there is some enum
{

    A = 0,
    B,
    C
}
```

And then this

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("TestCS");
var converter = new EnumConverter(assembly.GetType("TestCS.TestEnum"));
var enumValColl = converter.GetStandardValues();

foreach (var val in enumValColl)
    Debug.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", val, (int)val);
```

Output

> A = 0
>   B = 1
>   C = 2