# Get enum from ReflectedType

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting Enum value via reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3565310/getting-enum-value-via-reflection)

With `mytype.ReflectedType.GetFields()` I can get the constants defined in a c# class.

how can I get with `mytype.ReflectedType.XXX` a certain enum I have defined inside the c# class during **runtime**?

Comment: I do not know the enum during compile time. This is not a duplicate!

Comment: That's why it says Possible Duplicate ;-) FWIW if you can enumerate the members of the class, then this answer (and the answer from Marc Gravell) may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5006004/1073107

Comment: Your edit also changes the question a lot :-) Can you show us how you are injecting the enum at runtime?

Comment: I pass it to a method via: (typof(class.MyEnumDefinition)) at compile time ;P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enum isn't really a member of the class, it's only declared in the scope of the class. You can use the `GetNestedType` method to get a type that is declared inside another. Example:

```
public class Demo {
  public enum Values { Apha, Beta }
}

Type t = typeof(Demo).GetNestedType("Values");
```

Comment: typeof(mystuff).ReflectedType.GetNestedType("Values") helped me. Thanks Guffa!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try

```
(int)((reflectedType.GetEnumValues()
                    .Zip(reflectedType.GetEnumNames(), (v, n) => new { v, n })
                    .Where(p => p.n == FieldName)
                    .Single()).v)
```

This would give you the numeric value of your enum constant.
You cannot however get the enum value, since this requires knowing the real enum type at compile-time.